# How to retrieve Yahoo Weather RSS Feed in android?

Tags: android, rss

I would like to ask what have gone wrong with my coding?
Or is it Yahoo weather API need any  API KEY?
As I couldn't retrieve the RSS code for my Yahoo Weather.
The RSS Feed that I'm trying to retrieve from is 
http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=24703044&u=c

Advice needed.
Thanks

The below are my coding.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private RSSFeed myRssFeed = null;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      try {
  URL rssUrl = new URL("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=24703044&u=c");
  SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
  SAXParser mySAXParser = mySAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
  XMLReader myXMLReader = mySAXParser.getXMLReader();
  RSSHandler myRSSHandler = new RSSHandler();
  myXMLReader.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler);
  InputSource myInputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
  myXMLReader.parse(myInputSource);

  myRssFeed = myRSSHandler.getFeed();

 } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (SAXException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }

 if (myRssFeed!=null)
 {

  ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> adapter =
   new ArrayAdapter<RSSItem>(this,
     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myRssFeed.getList());
  setListAdapter(adapter);

 }
  }

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 Intent intent = new Intent(this,ShowDetails.class);
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString("keyTitle", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getTitle());
 bundle.putString("keyPsi", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getDescription());
 bundle.putString("keyLink", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getLink());
 bundle.putString("keyPubdate", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getPubdate());
 intent.putExtras(bundle);
      startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

RSSFeed.java

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

public class RSSFeed {
private String title = null;
private String yweather = null;
private String link = null;
private String pubdate = null;
private List<RSSItem> itemList;

RSSFeed(){
itemList = new Vector<RSSItem>(0);
}

void addItem(RSSItem item){
itemList.add(item);
}

RSSItem getItem(int location){
return itemList.get(location);
}

List<RSSItem> getList(){
return itemList;
}

void setTitle(String value)
{
title = value;
}
void setDescription(String value)
{
    yweather = value;
}
void setLink(String value)
{
link = value;
}
void setPubdate(String value)
{
pubdate = value;
}

String getTitle()
{
return title;
}
String getDescription()
{
return yweather;
}
String getLink()
{
return link;
}
String getPubdate()
{
return pubdate;
}

}
```

RSSHandler.java

```
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {

final int state_unknown = 0;
final int state_title = 1;
final int state_description = 2;
final int state_link = 3;
final int state_pubdate = 4;
int currentState = state_unknown;

RSSFeed feed;
RSSItem item;

boolean itemFound = false;

RSSHandler(){
}

RSSFeed getFeed(){
return feed;
}

@Override
public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
feed = new RSSFeed();
item = new RSSItem();

}

@Override
public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
itemFound = true;
item = new RSSItem();
currentState = state_unknown;
}
else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")){
currentState = state_title;
}
else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("description")){
currentState = state_description;
}
else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link")){
currentState = state_link;
}
else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubdate")){
currentState = state_pubdate;
}
else{
currentState = state_unknown;
}

}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
throws SAXException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
feed.addItem(item);
}
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
throws SAXException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

String strCharacters = new String(ch,start,length);

if (itemFound==true){
// "item" tag found, it's item's parameter
switch(currentState){
case state_title:
 item.setTitle(strCharacters);
 break;
case state_description:
 item.setDescription(strCharacters);
 break;
case state_link:
 item.setLink(strCharacters);
 break;
case state_pubdate:
 item.setPubdate(strCharacters);
 break;
default:
 break;
}
}
else{
// not "item" tag found, it's feed's parameter
switch(currentState){
case state_title:
 feed.setTitle(strCharacters);
 break;
case state_description:
 feed.setDescription(strCharacters);
 break;
case state_link:
 feed.setLink(strCharacters);
 break;
case state_pubdate:
 feed.setPubdate(strCharacters);
 break;
default:
 break;
}
}

currentState = state_unknown;
}


}
```

RSSItem.java

```
public class RSSItem {

private String title = null;
private String yweather = null;
private String link = null;
private String pubdate = null;

RSSItem(){
}

void setTitle(String value)
{
title = value;
}
void setDescription(String value)
{
    yweather = value;
}
void setLink(String value)
{
link = value;
}
void setPubdate(String value)
{
pubdate = value;
}

String getTitle()
{
return title;
}
String getDescription()
{
return yweather;
}
String getLink()
{
return link;
}
String getPubdate()
{
return pubdate;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return title;
}
}
```

ShowDetails.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ShowDetails extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.details);
 TextView detailsTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailstitle);
 TextView detailsDescription = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailspsi);
 TextView detailsPubdate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailspubdate);
 TextView detailsLink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailslink);

 Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();

      detailsTitle.setText(bundle.getString("keyTitle"));
      detailsDescription.setText(bundle.getString("keyPsi"));
      detailsPubdate.setText(bundle.getString("keyPubdate"));
      detailsLink.setText(bundle.getString("keyLink"));

}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Main ListView 
         Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
    -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

details.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >

<TextView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/detailstitle"
  android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/detailspsi"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
<TextView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:autoLink="web"
  android:id="@+id/detailslink"
    android:textSize="10sp" />
<TextView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/detailspubdate"
    android:textSize="10sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

rsslist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rowtext"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="25px"
android:textSize="10sp" />
```